# Instance variables and do loops in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I find my self often doing things like this in Ruby on Rails:

```
@count = 0

LineItem.all.each do |item|
     if (item.cart_id == @cart.id)
       @count += item.quantity
     end
end
```

So many things look wrong with this, but I want to initialize my variable (@count) before the loop, and then be able to use it after I'm out of the loop.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you are just collecting the `item.quantity` of all matching
items. This can be accomplished by

```
@count = LineItem.all.find_all{|i| i.cart_id == @cart.id}.map{|i| i.quantity}.inject(0,:+)
```

Do you mean that you might be doing something else with in the cart_id check?

Comment: Both this and the other answer work. This one seems to complete the queries faster. I'm using Postgres.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 6):

If you work with database you can do this more efficiently with sql request:

```
LineItem.where(:card_id => @card.id).sum('quantity')
```

This is equivalent sql query

```
SELECT SUM(items.identity) FROM items WHERE items.card_id = ?;
```